# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference - Android

Tags: android, json

I am new to Android, i have been trying JSON parsing using PHP and MYSQL, when i run app got this error.

**Error:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.admin.androidjsonparsing, PID: 13399
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
>                         at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
>                         at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
>                         at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:92)
>                         at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:108)
>                         at com.example.admin.androidjsonparsing.MainActivity.loadIntoListView(MainActivity.java:79)
>                         at com.example.admin.androidjsonparsing.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:22)
>                         at com.example.admin.androidjsonparsing.MainActivity$1GetJSON.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:51)
>                         at com.example.admin.androidjsonparsing.MainActivity$1GetJSON.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:38)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Here the **code:**

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.admin.androidjsonparsing;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    getJSON("http://192.168.1.4/AndroidJSONParsing/getdata.php");
}


private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {

    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                loadIntoListView(s);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }
                return sb.toString().trim();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
    getJSON.execute();
}

private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    String[] heroes = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        heroes[i] = obj.getString("name");
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, heroes);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.androidjsonparsing.MainActivity">


<!-- this is our listview where we will display the fetched data -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show response of api.

Answer (score 2):

Check for the null string.

```
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
       super.onPostExecute(s);
       if(s!=null){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                      loadIntoListView(s);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ...

```
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s) && s!=null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            loadIntoListView(s);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem are ocurred because your `String json` is not a valid json, maybe because it is `null` or `bad formated json`, then try as follow:

#### Step 1.

```
if (s!=null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) loadIntoListView(s);
```

#### Step 2.

```
private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            heroes[i] = obj.getString("name");
        }
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        //handler json exception
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, heroes);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also thrown (rather unexpectedly) if the URI is null or not set as in the following example

```
        URL url = new URL(xml_file);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

Error will be thrown on second line, if xml_file is empty (that is not set). Make sure it has a valid value. You can use `Log.e("App", "XML File is " + xml_file);` to check it value in he logs